# External POCO classes to Aspnetboilerplate AbpEntities. i.e. no inheritace possible

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

We have a pretty common situation and I'd like to understand the best-practice or trade-offs in Aspnetboilerplate/AspNetZero.com to handle this best.

We import a package (NuGet) of pure C# classes (POCO). These are shared across several system. In our AspNetZero server, we want these to be first class persistent objects. However, they can't inherit from Entity, since they come from the Nuget. What is the best practice here?

My ideas to date (not being the expert here, of course):

If we were to use these classes as EF Navigation Properties in Apb Entities, i.e. always use them as complex-type properties of an Abp Entity class, it could do the trick. In this scenario, one would not even need to define a DbSet, although one could (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application )

Alternatively, if we just reference these complex types from an Apb Entity, doesn't EF generate Entity-Proxies for these and automatically make them into EF Navigation Properties (see: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adonet/2009/12/22/poco-proxies-part-1/ ) or is this not an option the default Abp flow. We'd like to avoid too much custom code (risk).

Any other way via delegation?

Thanks for any Tips/Example/Info!